# Telit GL868-DUAL does not respond to AT commands

Tags: python, at-command, telit

I cannot send AT commands.
First, a program compiled in python by another developer was installed on this modem.

If you remove the SIM card and connect at 115200 baud, the following menu will appear:

```
ELIUS GSM-P RS485 V0.1
<P1> View statistics
<P2> Watchdog interval: 24 hours
<PR> Clear statistics
<MODE> Disabled
<IRCF> Interface: 9600 8N1
<HELP> Help on shell management.
```

Here it works only with commands in the menu, AT does not understand commands.

When connected at 9600 baud, the following is displayed:

```
...
import teutil # precompiled from teutil.pyo
import mainutil # precompiled from mainutil.pyo

*Modem initialization*
M: AT\R0 -> OK
M: AT+CLIP=1 -> OK
M: AT+CBST=7,0,1 -> OK
M: AT&D0 -> OK
M: AT+CREG? -> +CREG: 0.1

FINE
M: AT+CGATT=1 -> OK
M: AT#SCFG=1,1,300,90,60,50 -> OK
M: AT#SCFGEXT=1,1,0,0,0,0 -> OK
...
```

I have tried this part with and without a SIM card.

When I type the AT command, the characters "▒▒▒" appear. No response to Enter key.
I did not find any information about this in the search engine, so I turn to you.
Please, help.
Thanks in advance.